# How can i change background of the site on the click of the mouse in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to add some buttons on my site and change  the background when i click them.

```
<html>
<head>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE "JavaScript">
    function cambiaSfondo(code){
        document.sfonfo=code
    }
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
    <FORM>
        <input type = "button" name="button1" value="sfondo1" onClick='idk what to put here'>
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Answer (score 1):

`sfondo` is not a valid property

```
function cambiaSfondo(img){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
}


<input type = "button" name="button1" value="sfondo1" onClick="cambiaSfondo('/path/to/img')">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Comment: i have to change the image of the background! not the color

Comment: You didn't specify that! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Comment: String concatenation in JavaScript is done with `+` (plus), not with a `.` (dot).

Answer (score 0):

Working code here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script tpye="text/javascript">
   // $(document).ready(function() {
        function cambiaSfondo(img) {
            $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+img+')');
        }
   //});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <FORM> <input type = "button" name="button1" value="sfondo1" onClick="cambiaSfondo('search-icon-2x.png');"> </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you but his doesnt work yet:

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE "JavaScript">
        function cambiaSfondo(img){
     document.body.style.backgroundImage = img
        }
    </SCRIPT>

    <FORM>
        <input type = "button" name="button1" value="sfondo1" onClick= cambiaSfondo('Immagini/sfondo1.jpg')>
    </FORM>

Answer (score -1):

**First of all you don't have to use form because you are not getting or posting anything to server!**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor(){
            document.body.style.background="#000000";
        }
    </script >
</head>
<body>
       <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change any background property : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp

This is your exact case : [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_background)

Comment: He's now saying he wants to change the `backgroundImage`

Comment: @Kyra there is no such requirement in the question. But it's still possible to apply a background image with `background` shorthand.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my answer? Explanation about Down Vote Please??

Comment: Dunno, answer looks reasonable, except the link to W3Schools, probably.

Comment: Supplied link to W3Schools contains definition of background property and a working example of this exact case so i think in this particular case there is nothing wrong with the link.

Comment: Except it is being W3Schools, obviously. Among web developers it is known as inaccurate and urelaible source. See http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: You should ask yourself couple of questions: Is there anything wrong with this link in W3Schools - the answer is NO, are there any inaccuracies - the answer is NO, does it have a working example that is related to question that was asked - the answer is YES. So there is nothing wrong with this link despite the fact that its from  W3Schools.

Comment: I don't know if there are anything wrong with this particular link, that why I didn't vote for your answer so far. In general, W3Schools is B.A.D., why not link to some wikified reference like MDN or Webplatform?